# Prove inequality with two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to prove the inequality $$j^2-16w \ge 0$$

where $w$ is the area of a rectangle and $j$ is the perimeter.

I was going to use $$b^2-4ac \ge 0$$ but I don't know how.

Could someone point me in the right direction,

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hint: you know that $w$ is $s*t$, where $s$ and $t$ are the lengths of the sides. You also know that $j = 2s+2t$. Try going from there.

Comment: Perfect thank you, I should have seen that.

Comment: SO now I am left with $4s^2 + 4t^2 - 8st \ge $  How can I prove this using $b^2-4ac$

Comment: Right. So the trick is to show that the above is always at least zero. You don't *need* to use the discriminant of the quadratic formula ($b^2 - 4ac$), if you notice something about $4s^2 + 4t^2 - 8st$. (Hint: divide by 4 and you'll probably notice it faster.)

Comment: Okay, I still don't see it, could you explain a little further.

Comment: Ok, we need to show that $4s^2+4t^2-8st\geq 0$. This is the same as saying $s^2+t^2-2st\geq 0$, right? One way to show that something is nonnegative is to show that it's a square of something else. What is $s^2+t^2-2st$ the square of?

Comment: It is the square of $(s)+(t)+$ what squared gives a minus apart from $i$?

Comment: $s^2+t^2 - 2st = (s-t)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Let the sides be $x$ and $y$. The perimeter is $2(x+y)$, and the area is $xy$. Plug that into the equation and see what you get and how you can simplify it further.

Comment: Thank you, both answers we exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

For a rectangle,
$$\begin{align*}j&=2(L+B)\\ w&=LB\end{align*}\tag*{}$$

Now, if we consider a quadratic equation in $t$ with roots $L,B$:
$$t^2-t(L+B)+LB=0$$ 
$$t^2-\frac{j}{2}t+w=0$$
$$2t^2-jt+2w=0$$

Since lengths and breadths have real values,
$$\Delta\geq 0$$
$$b^2-4ac\geq0$$
$$ \boxed{j^2-16w\geq0}$$
*(Probably, 4 years too late to help the OP.)*